# A way to iterate through rows and columns (in a panda data frame), select rows and columns based on conditions to put into panda another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with over 1500 rows 
 a sample of the table is like so

```
Site 2019 2020 2021 ....
ABC   0    1     2
DEF   1    1     2
GHI   2    0     1
JKL   0    0     0 
MNO   2    1     1
```

I want to create a new dataframe which only selects sites and years if they have:

- a value in 2019
- if 2019 has a value greater that or equal to value in the next years
- if there is a greater value in the next year, then the value of the previous year
- if the next year has a value less than the previous year

so the out put for the example would be

```
Site 2019 2020 2021 ....
DEF   1    1     1
GHI   2    
MNO   2    1     1
```

DEF has got a 1 in 2021 because there is a one in 2020

I tried to use the following to find the rows with values in the 2019 column but

```
for i.j in df.iterrows(): 
  if when j=2 
    if i >0   
     return value
```

but I get syntax errors

Comment: What exactly is `when` in your code example? if it is not a declared variable that will give you an error, also to test a condition you have to use two equal signs:
`if j==2:` and also you need double points at the end of an `if` condition

Comment: Also you can only use `return` in a function.

Comment: what do you mean with `less value or equal to value in the next years`? do you mean less or equal compared to sum of next years? if not, how do you get the `MNO` row?

Comment: you need to filter and recreate a data frame like filter first in where 2019 > 0 `df_has2019 =  df['2019']>0` , then you can use `df_has2019` and check if value in column 2020 is greater than 2021. May be iterate `for col in df_has2019.columns`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looping the rows you can do:

```
df1 = df[(df[2019] > 0) & (df.loc[:, 2020:].min(axis=1) <= df.loc[:, 2019])]
cols = df1.columns.tolist()
for i in range(2, len(cols)):
    df1[cols[i]] = df1.loc[:, cols[i - 1: i + 1]].min(axis=1)
df1
```

Output:

```
     2019  2020  2021
DEF     1     1     1
GHI     2     0     0
MNO     2     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as you don't have too many columns. Add another comparison for each set of years that need to be compared. This will be a reference to the original df unless you use .copy() to make a deep copy.

```
new_df = df[(df['2019'] > 0) & (df['2019'] <= df['2020']) & (df['2020'] <= df['2021']) & (df['2021'] <= df['2022'])]
```

Comment: I have 22 columns unfortunately

Comment: You could filter for 2019 > 0 like my first filter. Then do an iteration with different columns using iloc